# Google Sheets: Filter; ignore until a word

Tags: google-sheets

I have multiple columns of keywords that I'm trying to filter certain words from which I have flattened. This has already been done with the following formula:

```
=iferror(filter(flatten(A8:A,G8:G,M8:M),flatten(A8:A,G8:G,M8:M)<>""),"")
```

However, I'd like a way to make a condition to ignore words until it comes across FALSE and stop on TRUE.

```
1
2
FALSE
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
TRUE
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
TRUE
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
FALSE
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
```

From this list, it should go down this list and ignore every word until it comes across FALSE, then filter all words in until it comes across TRUE, then ignore every word until it comes across FALSE. So in this list above, the final result should be:

```
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
```

Is it possible to add a filter condition that satisfies this request?

Edit: Here's a sheet to play around with.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1URoMNuISdfqohoOpc9p15LjKPE5qMNoFxfORLhjeVVQ/edit#gid=0

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with demo data and expected output(manually entered) so that it gives a clear picture for us to work it out

Comment: Here it is! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1URoMNuISdfqohoOpc9p15LjKPE5qMNoFxfORLhjeVVQ/edit#gid=0

Comment: So looking at the spreadsheet, I think you want a list of all classes in groups where checkboxes are unchecked.  Is that accurate?

Comment: That is indeed what I'm looking for! It does need to be a filter condition however, as this list will be used to filter with names later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,tocol({A:A,G:G,M:M},1,1),
       filter(Σ,scan(,Σ,lambda(a,c,ifs(c=FALSE,1,c=TRUE,,1,a))),Σ<>FALSE))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have addressed to your solution in the test sheet. The list works as expected, but I'm not sure how to make your function into a filter condition.

Comment: Added a formula to your sheet

Comment: Looks almost perfect! Because this function is a mystery to me there's one thing I can't quite figure out: if the class is empty, your formula spits out an empty row with a counter of 0. Is it possible to just skip that line altogether? I have added a footnote next to your updated formula.