# How to count number of unique cells, ignoring them if TRUE

Tags: google-sheets

6 months ago I asked for a count to unique cells, which worked beautifully here:
[Google Sheets: Filter; ignore until a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76187964/google-sheets-filter-ignore-until-a-word)

However now I want to count the number of activities instead. Problem being, the activity is before the TRUE/FALSE checkbox, so is it possible for lambda to retroactively work on previous element of the array? Or is it possible to reverse sort the entire array?

Kind answerer gave me this formula last time:

```
     Γ,filter(index(Σ,,1),scan(,index(Σ,,1),lambda(a,c,ifs(c=FALSE,1,c=TRUE,,1,a))),index(Σ,,3)=Y34),
       map(unique(Γ),lambda(z,{z,countif(Γ,z)})))
```

Test spreadsheet is here from 6 months ago:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1URoMNuISdfqohoOpc9p15LjKPE5qMNoFxfORLhjeVVQ/edit#gid=0

With the current set, based on the checkboxes, this is the result I want (all activities that have checkboxes set to FALSE):

```
Activity 5 3
Activity 7 1
Activity 8 2
```

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=index(let(Σ,tocol(if((islogical(A5:M60)=TRUE)*(A5:M60=FALSE),C3:O60,),1),Λ,unique(Σ),
       {Λ,countif(Σ,Λ)}))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. How should I make it work if I want to use indirect range? Say that I only want to make a range for Wednesday and Thursday, not Friday. I can use: INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,1) & ":" & ADDRESS(match("Friday",A:A,0),17)), but replacing your ranges with this indirect range causes it to break.

Comment: This is the code I tried to use to incorporate your answer: ```=INDEX(LET(
  Σ, TOCOL(IF((ISLOGICAL
(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,1) & ":" & ADDRESS(match("Friday",A:A,0),13)))=TRUE)*
(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,1) & ":" & ADDRESS(match("Friday",A:A,0),13))=FALSE),
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,1) & ":" & ADDRESS(match("Friday",A:A,0),15)),), 1),
  Λ, UNIQUE(Σ),
  {Λ, COUNTIF(Σ, Λ)}
))```